# Python 'invalid syntax' error on Android

Tags: android, python, syntax-error

I have a problem with Python on Android. My code works fine with Windows - however, on Android 6.1 with SPMC it gives this error:

```
SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.semperpax.spmc16/files/.spmc/addons/context.addtolib/context.py', 104, 45, '        curVisCond         = {self.container, \n'))
```

And I don't understand why. Part of Code:

```
  def doAction(self):

    curVisCond         = {self.container,
                          TAG_CND_NOTFOUND  if not self.isFound        else TAG_CND_FOUND,
                          TAG_CND_NEWSRC    if self.isNewSource        else TAG_CND_OLDSRC,
                          TAG_CND_NEWFRC    if self.isNewFolSource     else TAG_CND_OLDFRC,
                          TAG_TYP_FOLDER    if self.items.vidIsFolder  else TAG_TYP_FILE,
                          TAG_CND_LISTEMPTY if self.items.vidIsEmpty   else Empty,
                          TAG_CND_NOUPD     if not addon.ADDUPD        else Empty}
```

Comment: What version of Python is it? Maybe it's from before set literal syntax existed. i.e. 2.6 or lower.

Comment: Android - python 2.6, win - 2.7, but as i now 2.6/2.7 do not have such literal syntax differences

Answer (score 0):

Set literal syntax was [introduced in 3.1 and backported to 2.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.7.html). It is not valid syntax in Python 2.6.

Use a list literal, and convert it using the `set` type.

```
curVisCond         = set([self.container,
                          TAG_CND_NOTFOUND  if not self.isFound        else TAG_CND_FOUND,
                          TAG_CND_NEWSRC    if self.isNewSource        else TAG_CND_OLDSRC,
                          TAG_CND_NEWFRC    if self.isNewFolSource     else TAG_CND_OLDFRC,
                          TAG_TYP_FOLDER    if self.items.vidIsFolder  else TAG_TYP_FILE,
                          TAG_CND_LISTEMPTY if self.items.vidIsEmpty   else Empty,
                          TAG_CND_NOUPD     if not addon.ADDUPD        else Empty])
```